# Bulk document download from Docusign

Tags: c#, rest, docusignapi

I have a requirement to download all signed documents that were signed through Docusign based on a Template.

Is there a RESTful command that will return a PDF of all signed documents in a single document? I don't want to recreate the wheel on my end if something like this exists.

Effectively:
I'd like to take a specific template, and use that ID to retrieve all signed documents as a single PDF .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to retrieve documents for multiple envelopes in a single API call. You will have to iterate through the list of your envelopes and make a getEnvelopeDocuments API call for each envelope.

You can use the [getEnvelopeDocuments](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeDocuments/get/)  to download all the documents in a single envelope.

- The following GET request retrieves a PDF that contains the combined content of all documents and the certificate in a given envelope.

  ```
  GET /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/documents/combined
  ```
- The following GET request retrieves a ZIP archive that contains all of the PDF documents, the certificate, and any .WAV files used for voice authentication.

  ```
  GET /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/documents/archive
  ```

---

Edit: **Implementing Docusign Connect.**

You can leverage [Docusign Webhooks](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/api-overview#webhooks) to transport the completed documents back to your app whenever an Envelope status changes.

See [eventNotfication.includeDocuments](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/#definition-eventNotification) property

Comment: That's what I thought. We might have 300 people sign based off a single template and I was hoping for a simpler solution to retrieving all these stitched rather than doing 300 pings to Docusign.

Comment: @RyanTernier You can also implement Docusign Webhooks. You will automatically receive documents when an envelope status changes .. https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/api-overview#webhooks

Comment: @RyanTernier Updated the answer with information related to docusign connect.